# EAAccessory ReadStream is very slow in IOS, how to speed up?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, eaaccessory

We are working on writing application to read data from Bluetooth 2.1+ EDR MFI registered external device. While read each time we suppose to read around 1300 bytes of data as one block need to be Downloaded. Following code snippet using to readStream

```
     # define EAD_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 512
    uint8_t buf[EAD_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ([[_session inputStream] hasBytesAvailable])
            {
                NSInteger bytesRead = [[_session inputStream] read:buf maxLength:EAD_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];

                for (int i = 0 ; i < bytesRead ; i++)
                {
                    [frame appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x ",buf[i]]];
                }
            }
```

but stream not able to read one block(1300 bytes) at one short. it read the data in 3-4 chunks.Each block taking 600- 700 milliseconds.i suppose read 100 blocks(each contains 1300 bytes). I have following three questions

1. How to reduce the download time from 600 ms to 100-200 ms?
2. How to read full block data at same time?
3. Is it operating system/power management related in iOS?

Am i doing anything wrong?, kindly help to over come this issue.

Comment: try to increase the buffer size i.e from 512 to 1024

Comment: @kumar : did you guys found any solution, i am struggling with the same issue. i have increase the buffer size to 1532 and i am expecting 1500 bytes. but no help.
please provide any solution

Comment: Bluetooth RFCOMM connection cannot transfer large data blocks by default. There is a max packet size (MTU) on both sides which is negotiated by connection so the lowest value is taken.